# Siteminder Max Timeout

Tags: single-sign-on, session-timeout, siteminder

At my place of employment, we are using CA's Siteminder to implement a single sign on for our applications. We have had issues with users "timing out" after seemingly random times and even while doing work.

Took us a while, but we finally figured it out. Siteminder has a setting called "max timeout" which basically causes the user's session to be invalidated after two hours...

I can't for the life of me figure out what the hell you would use that for?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Max timeout setting is meant to ensure that any cookies that are too old are removed. Unless you are using the Siteminder session store, SM cookies are vulnerable to being stolen and then replayed. The max timeout ensures that even if a cookie has been stolen.. it cannot be used for more than the max timeout regardless of the user continuously browsing and refreshing the session.